# Routing in dotnet core 3

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am useing `[Route("/{controller}/{action}/{name}")]`

I have an action that takes the name of an item as an argument, and the name can have spaces in it, so when it shows in the URL they replace spaces with %20 how can I change the spaces to a dash (-) without messing the code.

Answer (score 0):

`ASCII Encoding Reference` is a default role that you can't change it . It just replaces the original Character with another Character and does not change its value.

[image]

Comment: So the name I passed must not contain a space if I want it to look good

Comment: Hi, `%20` is `space` in url , it does not affect the result . So in general, we only need Url to navigate and pass parameters normally, and don't care about the form of the content in the url. If you don't want `%20` to appear in url, the name can't contain a `space`. If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? Refer to:[How to accept as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks.